# Single Table Inheritance (STI) parent ActiveRecord .subclasses .descendants returns empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, single-table-inheritance, ruby-2.0

I have a STI in place for 10 models inheriting from one `ActiveRecord::Base` model.

```
class Listing::Numeric < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Listing::AverageDuration < Listing::Numeric
end

class Listing::TotalViews < Listing::Numeric
end
```

There are 10 such models those inherit from `Listing::Numeric`

In rails console, when I try for `.descendants` or `.subclasses` it returns an empty array.

```
Listing::Numeric.descendants
=> []

Listing::Numeric.subclasses
=> []
```

Ideally this should work.

Any ideas why its not returning the expected subclasses ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped me

`config.autoload_paths += %W( #{config.root}/app/models/listings )`

Taken from here - http://hakunin.com/rails3-load-paths

Answer (score 8):

This will work only if all the inherited classes are referenced in some running code as rails will load the classes when required then only it will be added as descendants

For eg:

```
Listing::Numeric.descendants.count
=> 0

Listing::AverageDuration
Listing::TotalViews

Listing::Numeric.descendants.count
=> 2
```

Comment: Doesn't rails loads the classes on initialization ?

Comment: It happens in production, but not in development. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html for further informatinon

Answer (score 6):

Old Q, but for anyone else like me who get confused with empty lists for subclasses `MyClass.subclasses =>  []`

You need to explicitly set the dependency to your MySubclass class.

```
class MyClass < ApplicationRecord
end
require_dependency 'my_subclass'
```

```
$ MyClass.subclasses
=> ['MySubclass']
```

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoloading-and-sti

Answer (score 1):

Execute `Rails.application.eager_load!` before calling the .descendants method.